# PHP GD2 Images not printing

Tags: php, cordova, gd2

Recently we launched a in store activation that has you take a photo with a Galaxy Tab 2 and then feeds it to our central server. This is Done with Phonegap. On the server we use PHP and GD2 to generate the images. Everything works on the server and the images are created perfectly, the problem comes when we want to print these photos out with a printer. Currently we are using a HITI Photo Printer, but the same issue occurs on our normal in house printer, on the in house printer it does print the photo but its comes out so small no bigger than 4mm X 2mm on the page.

Below is the code I am using for generating the JPEG on the sever with PHP:

```
//define image name
$image_name = $this->genUID() .'.jpg';

//get image attributes
list($curWidth, $curHeight, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($files['my_picture']['tmp_name']);

//create image in today's directory
$nI = imagecreatefromjpeg($files['my_picture']['tmp_name']);
$nP = imagecreatetruecolor($this->minimum_image_width, $this->minimum_image_height);
$widthResizeRatio = ($this->minimum_image_width / $curWidth);
$newWidth = $this->minimum_image_width;
$newHeight = round(($curHeight * $widthResizeRatio),0);
$offsetX = 0;
$offsetY = 180;
imagecopyresampled($nP, $nI, 0, 0, $offsetX, $offsetY, $newWidth, $newHeight, $curWidth, $curHeight);
imageinterlace($nP, true);
imagejpeg($nP, $this->image_directory .'/'. $this->curDate .'/'. $image_name, 100);
imagedestroy($nI);
imagedestroy($nP);
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You said all the images on the server are created perfectly...I would test this claim more carefully.  If it is indeed true, the issue lies with how you send the images to your printer or how the printer handles the images once it receives them.  In either situation I don't think you are going to get much help here.....I could be wrong. GL.

Comment: Howzit, Thx. When I print the images from my PC to the printer its fine, unfortunately the setup requires that the images be placed on a USB flash drive and then plugged into the printer directly and this is where it goes wrong.

Comment: So it sounds like the images are being created fine and thus the issue isn't with your code.  Explore how the images are sent and handled by the printer